# How can i check a string whether it contains letters of a given word by user

Tags: java, string, letter, contain

how can i check a string whether it contains letters of a given word by user like

```
Enter the pattern string: shl

Enter a string: school

shl occurs in ”school”

Enter a string: okul

shl does NOT occur in ”okul”

Enter a string: salaries are neither high nor low

shl occurs in ”salaries are neither high nor low”

Enter a string: This is a good school, isn’t it? 

shl occurs in ”This is a good school, isn’t it?”

Enter a string: I love programming 

shl does NOT occur in ”I love programming”





if (occursIn(pattern,str)){

                System.out.println(pattern + " occurs in " + str);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(pattern + " does not occurs in " + str);
            }

public static boolean occursIn(String pattern, String str){

for(int i=0;pattern.charAt(i)<=str.length();i++){

        if(str.contains(pattern.charAt(i))){
            return true;
    }
        else {
            return false;
    }
}
```

}

it doesnt work in a method. Im trying for 5 hours please help me !!

i cant compare all of the letters and return them to the main method

Comment: Try it yourself, post your attempt if you can't solve it, then we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following code (I have tested it):

```
public class OccursIn {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pattern = "s*h*l";
        String str = "love hss";
        if (occursIn(pattern, str)) {
            System.out.println(pattern + " occurs in " + str);
        } else {
            System.out.println(pattern + " does not occurs in " + str);
        }
    }

    public static boolean occursIn(String pattern, String str) {
        for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length(); i++) {
            String c = pattern.substring(i, i + 1);
            if (!"*".equalsIgnoreCase(c) && !str.contains(c)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
s*h*l occurs in love hss
```

Comment: thank you very much for help. i want to ask you one more question if pattern includes wild character like "*" in addition to any other character. Each occurrence of the wild card character represents a sequence of any characters. what is the code can be like ?

Comment: @AliMercan Wait... just want to confirm, should the order of the characters in `pattern` be correct in `str`? I mean, "shl" surely occurs in "school", but does it occur in "love ssh" or not?

Comment: shl occurs in love ssh also s*h*l occurs in love ssh i just want to ignore "*" sign

Comment: Are you here ? I just want to add " *(star) " character as a wild card. I mean * occurs with every character. Also shl should be occur in love ssh. This is the last think i want to find out how it works. Thank you for your helps.

Comment: im sending you to the all information to write this code.

Comment: 2. Write a program that requests a pattern string from the user. The pattern includes wild card character “*” in addition to any other characters. Each occurrence of the wild chard character represents a sequence of any characters. After getting the pattern, the program continuously requests the user to enter a string and checks if the pattern occurs in the string using a method public static boolean occursIn(String pattern, String str). The program will exit when the user enters “exit”.

Comment: @AliMercan I see, please see the modified answer, which will ignore `*` in the pattern. I have tested it as well.

Comment: but now the s * h * l does not occurs with love hss. The pattern should be occur with every string which they have the same letters though they are not in the same order.

Comment: @AliMercan Did you add spaces (" ") in the pattern? I just tried the pattern without spaces (`s*h*l`) and it works fine.

Comment: no ignore the spaces i tried ( s*h*l ) too, it works fine when "str" is "school" but it doesnt work when "str" is "love hss"

Comment: the stars doesnt shows up in the comment because of this i used spaces.

Comment: @AliMercan I just edited my answer to contain full code and output. The pattern `s*h*l` seems to work when `str` is `love hss`?

Comment: @AliMercan Or, do you want to ignore both star ("*") and space (" ") in the pattern?

Comment: but what happens when the user wants to write any string like " This is a good school, isn’t it?" it has the same letters with "pattern" but not in the same order

Comment: Yes it will be matched. You can add a line in my main function like  `System.out.println(occursIn("s*h*l", " This is a good school, isn’t it?"));`. It will return true.

Comment: look i dont want to add line like you add in main function. i just want to ignore the order of letters. im very desperate right now. the users can be write anything as "str" like "This is a good school, isn’t it?" " love hss" " asdkasdshlshdlhs" i mean anyhting.

Comment: @AliMercan Currently the order of the letters "is" ignored as you mentioned. Please specify a pair of `pattern` and `str` which you think is not working well (i.e., return correct boolean value from `occursIn()` function) based on my current code.

Comment: im inputting (s * h * l) without spaces in "pattern" string. then inputting love hss in "str" string and it says me the "pattern" does not occurs with "str".

Comment: @AliMercan Does your pattern contain parenthesis? Say, first is `(s * h * l)`, second is `(s*h*l)`, third is `s * h * l`, fourth is `s*h*l`. Which is your pattern among this four?

Comment: im returning same as you in occursIn() method and the code in the main method is like if (occursIn(pattern,str)){
              System.out.println(pattern + " occurs in " + str);
             }
             else{
              System.out.println(pattern + " does not occurs in " + str);
             }

Comment: the fourth is my pattern

Comment: @AliMercan Okay, I changed my answer following your main function. Please try and see if our output are the same.

Comment: can you just try instead of writing String str = "love hss";       first ask from user to enter an input like    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);                                                                   System.out.println("please enter an input"); and then   String str=input.next();             in this code the love hss doesnt work

Comment: Please try nextLine() instead of next() - does problem remains?

Comment: Now we are done. Thanks for spending your time with my ridiculous problem. Have a good day Mr. Kuo

Comment: @AliMercan Great to know that! Please "accept" my answer by checking the green check under my answer. Happy weekend :-)

Comment: @AliMercan Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You are returning too soon. BTW, there are cleaner ways to do this, but I'm just adjusting your code sample.

```
public static boolean occursIn(String pattern, String str){
    boolean allLettersFound = true;

    for(int i=0;pattern.charAt(i)<=str.length();i++){
        if(!str.contains(pattern.charAt(i))){
            allLettersFound = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return allLettersFound;
}
```

Comment: it still gives me error about "contains" word in for loop. "The method contains(CharSequence) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments(char)"

Comment: Try @Tsung-Ting Kuo's solution. He said he tested his out, I just fixed the early return problem.